# Dynamic attribute value element locator in Protractor

Tags: javascript, function, attributes, protractor

When I add a new button with some value it gets dynamically added into DOM. Non-Angular HTML element for this button is:

```
<li class="ui-state-default droppable ui-sortable-handle" id="element_98" data-value="2519">
    25.19 EUR
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default removeParent">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true">
</span>
</button>
</li>
```

Once I remove this button I want to check it is not present anymore. Element that I'm searching for is `data-value="2519"`and this could be anything I set, like for example 2000, 1000, 500, 1050,...

In page object file I have tried to use the following:

```
this.newValueButtonIsNotPresent = function(item) {
        newValueButton = browser.element(by.id("containerQUICK_ADD_POINTS")).all(by.css('[data-value="' + item + '"]'));
        return newValueButton.not.isPresent();
    };
```

And in spec file I call this function as follows:

```
var twentyEurosButtonAttributeValue = '2000';

describe("....
    it ("...
        expect(predefined.newValueButtonIsNotPresent(twentyEurosButtonAttributeValue)).toBeTruthy();
```

I know this is not correct, but how I can achieve something like that or is there another way?

Answer (score 1):

Stupid me, I found a simple solution. Instead dynamically locating an element I located the first on the list, which is always the one, which was newly added and then checked if it's text does not match:

Page object file:

```
this.newValueButtonIsNotPresent = function() {
        newValueButton = browser.element(by.id("containerQUICK_ADD_POINTS")).all(by.tagName('li')).first();
        return newValueButton.getText();
    };
```

Spec file:

```
// verify element 20.00 EUR is not present
predefined.newValueButtonIsNotPresent().then(function(value) {
    expect(value).not.toEqual(twentyEurosText);
});
```